# Unparseable date error using Hashmap,GraphView in Android

Tags: java, android, date, hashmap

I am making a graph of date on x axis and float value on y-axis.I have sorted the Hashmap for timestamp(x values) and then adding data points in graph in `date,float` format. I am getting the following error.Please guide.

Here's my code:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : sortedList.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
            String tagName = entry.getKey();
            long timestampString =  Long.parseLong(tagName);
            String value = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").
                    format(new java.util.Date(timestampString * 1000));
            String newval=value.substring(0, value.indexOf(' '));
            Date date= new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            try {
                 date=fmtOut.parse(newval);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            String tagNameY=entry.getValue();
            addEntry(date,tagNameY);
        }
```

Here's my error:

```
    addEntry: value of Y axis is 676.32947
I/System.out: 1477526400 682.2239625
W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "27/10/2016"
W/System.err:     at android.icu.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:651)
W/System.err:     at com.example.garima.bitcoingraph.MainActivity$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:344)
W/System.err:     at com.example.garima.bitcoingraph.MainActivity$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:303)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
I/MainActivity: addEntry: value of Y axis is 682.22394
I/System.out: 1465862400 685.2418749999999
W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "14/06/2016"
```

Comment: conflict with `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` vs `"27/10/2016"`

Comment: for test case set `String value = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").`

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "05/01/2017 01:00:00"
W/System.err:     at android.icu.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:651)

Comment: changed it and got this err

Comment: then add **fmtOut** `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` instead of `"dd/MM/yyyy"`

Comment: I don't understand why do you create the date in one format to change it some lines after. create it directly with your desider format

Comment: what is the op of `newval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the string date in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` with this line

```
String value = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").
                    format(new java.util.Date(timestampString * 1000));
```

You obtain something like `21/01/2017 13:41:05`. So when you try to parse it with this line

```
SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

the two formats don't match and your parse fail. Note that `dd/MM/yyyy` is different from `dd-MM-yyyy`

Changing this line

```
SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

to this line

```
SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

should solve the problem

Comment: please explain the changes

Answer (score 2):

### Unparseable Date

This is a checked exception an it can occur when you fail to parse a String that is ought to have a special format.

Just use

```
 SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Either you compare all Result with **`dd/MM/yyyy`** **FORMAT** or **`dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`**

**Why Problem**

Date String **Conflict** . **FORMAT** Mismatch .
You can't parse **27/10/2016** with **dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss**

Comment: he is splitting dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss string in two parts

Comment: @firegloves indeed .Main problem is different  `FORMAT`